# R STUDIO: I am not able to read special characteres like Ü in the .csv

Tags: r, csv, ggplot2

I am new to R and I have a problem reading a .csv online

This is the .csv = https://dadesobertes.gva.es/dataset/15810be9-d797-4bf3-b37c-4c922bee8ef8/resource/a5140630-325a-4d54-b9e4-66216405164b/download/2020-05-31_casospormunicipio.csv

I am trying to read, but broke at the first Ü character

¿How should do it?

this is my code:

```
library(tidyverse)

library('data.table') 

fread('https://dadesobertes.gva.es/dataset/15810be9-d797-4bf3-b37c-4c922bee8ef8/resource/a5140630-325a-4d54-b9e4-66216405164b/download/2020-05-31_casospormunicipio.csv', header = TRUE, sep = ";", encoding = 'UTF-8')

dff <- read.csv("https://dadesobertes.gva.es/dataset/15810be9-d797-4bf3-b37c-4c922bee8ef8/resource/a5140630-325a-4d54-b9e4-66216405164b/download/2020-05-31_casospormunicipio.csv",fileEncoding = "UTF-8", header = TRUE, sep = ";")


dff %>%
  mutate(Municipio = fct_reorder(Municipio, Casos.PCR.)) %>%


  ggplot(aes(x=Municipio, y=Casos.PCR.)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=0.6) + coord_flip()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your script: change fileEncoding to encoding, i.e.:

```
dff <- read.csv("https://dadesobertes.gva.es/dataset/15810be9-d797-4bf3-b37c-4c922bee8ef8/resource/a5140630-325a-4d54-b9e4-66216405164b/download/2020-05-31_casospormunicipio.csv",encoding= "UTF-8", header = TRUE, sep = ";")
```

Comment: most welcome - please mark as answer if it helped, much appreciated.